# How to scale custom view across different devices

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-view

I have the following code for displaying an image on the users screen with a rectangle drawn around the face:

```
public class AndroidFaceDetector extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setContentView(new myView(this));
    }

    private class myView extends View {

        private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
        private int numberOfFace = 5;
        private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
        private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
        float myEyesDistance;
        int numberOfFaceDetected;

        Bitmap myBitmap;

        public myView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/face.jpg", BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);

            imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
            imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
            myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
            myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                    numberOfFace);
            numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
            myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
                Face face = myFace[i];
                PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
                face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
                myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
                canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance),
                        (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance), myPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It displays the following on my Sony Ericsson x8:

[image: x8 screenshot]

Here is the display on a sony xperia:

[image]

Does anybody know how to scale the image so it fits the screen of any device?? Thanks !

**Update**
I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    height=metrics.heightPixels/metrics.xdpi;
    width=metrics.widthPixels/metrics.ydpi;
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(new myView(this));
}

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
            Face face = myFace[i];
            PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
            face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
            myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
            canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance), myPaint);
        }


        canvas.scale(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scale the canvas before you draw to it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale(float,%20float)

Edit: Or generate a new bitmap as Gabe mentions. On modern devices that support hardware acceleration scaling using the canvas method is extremely cheap at runtime, but keeping the larger bitmap in memory will consume more memory than keeping a smaller version. If you already need to keep the full-res version in memory for some other reason, scaling it when drawing will be more efficient on newer devices. If you never need the full-res version again, creating a scaled bitmap and throwing away the original will use less memory if the source image was larger.

Comment: How can I figure out how much to scale it by? I update my question with what I have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Scale it by view.getWidth()/bitmap.getWidth()  in the x and view.getHeight()/bitmap.getHeight() in the y .

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float height=metrics.heightPixels/metrics.xdpi;
float width=metrics.widthPixels/metrics.ydpi;
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

When drawing the bitmap, use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale the bitmap to your view's width and height.  Then it will fit.  Make sure to keep any points on the bitmap consistent-  use either the position in the original bitmap or in the scaled bitmap, don't mix and match or you'll have odd results.